# How to detect, and color the left or right block of each table, depending on conditions and random values ​by JavaScript-jQ

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
setInterval(function () {
                for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

                    var getNum = $('#res' + i).html(number);
                    if (getNum.html() >= 50) {
                        $('#res' + i + 'mult').html("right");
                        var num = 1;
                        for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
                            $("#row" + num++ + "-" + 2).css("background-color", 'red');
                        }

                    } else {
                        var num2 = 1;
                        $('#res' + i + 'mult').html("left");
                        $("#row" + num2++ + "-" + num2).css("background-color", 'yellow');
                    }

                }
            },
            1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>1</title>
    <script src="../!Needs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 20px;

        }

        table {
            width: 200px;

        }

        #shapedive {
            height: 500px;
            border-radius: 30pt;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="bigTable" border="1" style="text-align: center;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">Pin</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">Number</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">Direction</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=pin>1</td>
                    <td id="res1"></td>
                    <td id="res1mult"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=pin>2</td>
                    <td id="res2"></td>
                    <td id="res2mult"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=pin>3</td>
                    <td id="res3"></td>
                    <td id="res3mult"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=pin>4</td>
                    <td id="res4"></td>
                    <td id="res4mult"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=pin>5</td>
                    <td id="res5"></td>
                    <td id="res5mult"></td>

            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="shape">
            <div id="shapedive">
                <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row1-1">*</td>
                        <td id="row1-2">Starter</td>
                        <td id="row1-3">*</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="text-align: center " border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row2-1">1</td>
                        <td id="row2-2">2</td>
                        <td id="row2-3">3</td>
                        <td id="row2-4">4</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="text-align: center " border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row3-1">1</td>
                        <td id="row3-2">2</td>
                        <td id="row3-3">3</td>
                        <td id="row3-4">4</td>
                        <td id="row3-5">5</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row4-1">1</td>
                        <td id="row4-2">2</td>
                        <td id="row4-3">3</td>
                        <td id="row4-4">4</td>
                        <td id="row4-5">5</td>
                        <td id="row4-6">6</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row5-1">1</td>
                        <td id="row5-2">2</td>
                        <td id="row5-3">3</td>
                        <td id="row5-4">4</td>
                        <td id="row5-5">5</td>
                        <td id="row5-6">6</td>
                        <td id="row5-7">7</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row6-1">1</td>
                        <td id="row6-2">2</td>
                        <td id="row6-3">3</td>
                        <td id="row6-4">4</td>
                        <td id="row6-5">5</td>
                        <td id="row6-6">6</td>
                        <td id="row6-7">7</td>
                        <td id="row6-8">8</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make a simple game. We have two tables. The table on the top, which has 5 rows and 3 columns - including: pin, random number and direction (left or right) - and the bottom table which has 6 rows. The cell at the first row and second column (`$("#row1-2")`) is the beginning of our game.

The Left/Right values in the top table determine the direction, left or right, of the cell that should be painted in the corresponding row in the bottom table.

We have a simple condition to get a direction value. We generate a random number. If the random number is > 50, the direction is set to `"right"`; otherwise, it is set to `"left"`.

That is, if, for example, the values ​​in the top table were as follows:

`Pin 1 => 28 => Left`

`Pin 2 => 9  => Left`

`Pin 3 => 56 => Right`

`Pin 4 => 99 => Right`

`Pin 5 => 14 => Left`

Then, in the bottom table, the game is started from the starter column, and as we incrementally descend the rows, the column that gets painted is determined by the `"left"` or `"right"` values that were generated above.

In the bottom table, because the value of pin 1 (`28`) is less than 50, the painted column will move to the `"left"` from the starter block `$("#row1-2")`: `$("#row2-2")`.

And because the value of pin 2 (`9`) also maps to `"left"`, the painted column in the next row should also be to the `"left"`: `$("#row3-2")`.

For pin 3, we have `"right"`, so the column in the next row to the right of the last painted cell should be painted: `$("#row4-3")`.

...and so on until all the rows have a painted cell.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>1</title>
    <script src="../!Needs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 20px;

        }

        table {
            width: 200px;

        }

        #shapedive {
            height: 500px;
            border-radius: 30pt;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="bigTable" border="1" style="text-align: center;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">Pin</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">Number</td>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">Direction</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=pin>1</td>
                    <td id="res1"></td>
                    <td id="res1mult"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=pin>2</td>
                    <td id="res2"></td>
                    <td id="res2mult"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=pin>3</td>
                    <td id="res3"></td>
                    <td id="res3mult"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=pin>4</td>
                    <td id="res4"></td>
                    <td id="res4mult"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=pin>5</td>
                    <td id="res5"></td>
                    <td id="res5mult"></td>

            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="shape">
            <div id="shapedive">
                <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row1-1">*</td>
                        <td id="row1-2">Starter</td>
                        <td id="row1-3">*</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="text-align: center " border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row2-1">1</td>
                        <td id="row2-2">2</td>
                        <td id="row2-3">3</td>
                        <td id="row2-4">4</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="text-align: center " border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row3-1">1</td>
                        <td id="row3-2">2</td>
                        <td id="row3-3">3</td>
                        <td id="row3-4">4</td>
                        <td id="row3-5">5</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row4-1">1</td>
                        <td id="row4-2">2</td>
                        <td id="row4-3">3</td>
                        <td id="row4-4">4</td>
                        <td id="row4-5">5</td>
                        <td id="row4-6">6</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row5-1">1</td>
                        <td id="row5-2">2</td>
                        <td id="row5-3">3</td>
                        <td id="row5-4">4</td>
                        <td id="row5-5">5</td>
                        <td id="row5-6">6</td>
                        <td id="row5-7">7</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="row6-1">1</td>
                        <td id="row6-2">2</td>
                        <td id="row6-3">3</td>
                        <td id="row6-4">4</td>
                        <td id="row6-5">5</td>
                        <td id="row6-6">6</td>
                        <td id="row6-7">7</td>
                        <td id="row6-8">8</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<script>
    setInterval(function () {
                for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

                    var getNum = $('#res' + i).html(number);
                    if (getNum.html() >= 50) {
                        $('#res' + i + 'mult').html("right");
                        var num = 1;
                        for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
                            $("#row" + num++ + "-" + 2).css("background-color", 'red');
                        }

                    } else {
                        var num2 = 1;
                        $('#res' + i + 'mult').html("left");
                        $("#row" + num2++ + "-" + num2).css("background-color", 'yellow');
                    }

                }
            },
            1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it very difficult to synchronize the cells in the top table with those in the second. One problem is that row 1 in the first table has a left/right value; but in the second table, row 1 is the Starter - the left/right decisions don't start until row 2. I would simplify this by making the corresponding rows in the two tables have the same number. I would also 0-index the rows and columns (as opposed to having them start at 1) because this  is easier for my brain as it is consistent with arrays and typical loops.

To determine which column is active as we descend the table, it was helpful for me to realize that a "left" step means the column index stays the same in the next row, and a "right" step means the index increases by 1.

We can declare a variable to track the current column. We will start it at `1` since we know the "Starter" is at the `[1]` index of its row: `const col = 1;`. Then, as we loop through the rows, we increment `col` by `1` if we are stepping right or `0` if we are stepping left.

We can package our game logic into a `play` function and invoke it once - `play()` - or at an interval - `setInterval(play, 1000)`.

```js
const play = () => {
  let col = 1;
  
  // reset the game board
  $('td').css('background-color', 'white');
  $('td#starter').css('background-color', 'red');

  for (let row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
    const pin = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    const isRight = pin > 50;

    col += (isRight ? 1 : 0);

    $(`#res${row}`).text(pin);
    $(`#res${row}mult`).text(isRight ? 'right' : 'left');
    $(`#row${row}-${col}`).css("background-color", isRight ? 'yellow' : 'red');
  }
};

play();
//setInterval(play, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
}

table {
  width: 200px;
}

#shapedive {
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 30pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="bigTable" border="1" style="text-align: center;">
        <tr>
          <td style="font-weight: bold">Pin</td>
          <td style="font-weight: bold">Number</td>
          <td style="font-weight: bold">Direction</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class=pin>1</td>
          <td id="res0"></td>
          <td id="res0mult"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class=pin>2</td>
          <td id="res1"></td>
          <td id="res1mult"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class=pin>3</td>
          <td id="res2"></td>
          <td id="res2mult"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class=pin>4</td>
          <td id="res3"></td>
          <td id="res3mult"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class=pin>5</td>
          <td id="res4"></td>
          <td id="res4mult"></td>

      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="shape">
      <div id="shapedive">
        <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
          <tr>
            <td>*</td>
            <td id="starter">Starter</td>
            <td>*</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="text-align: center " border="1">
          <tr>
            <td id="row0-0">1</td>
            <td id="row0-1">2</td>
            <td id="row0-2">3</td>
            <td id="row0-3">4</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="text-align: center " border="1">
          <tr>
            <td id="row1-0">1</td>
            <td id="row1-1">2</td>
            <td id="row1-2">3</td>
            <td id="row1-3">4</td>
            <td id="row1-4">5</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
          <tr>
            <td id="row2-0">1</td>
            <td id="row2-1">2</td>
            <td id="row2-2">3</td>
            <td id="row2-3">4</td>
            <td id="row2-4">5</td>
            <td id="row2-5">6</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
          <tr>
            <td id="row3-0">1</td>
            <td id="row3-1">2</td>
            <td id="row3-2">3</td>
            <td id="row3-3">4</td>
            <td id="row3-4">5</td>
            <td id="row3-5">6</td>
            <td id="row3-6">7</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="text-align: center" border="1">
          <tr>
            <td id="row4-0">1</td>
            <td id="row4-1">2</td>
            <td id="row4-2">3</td>
            <td id="row4-3">4</td>
            <td id="row4-4">5</td>
            <td id="row4-5">6</td>
            <td id="row4-6">7</td>
            <td id="row4-7">8</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have also created an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/g2zr3tbc/).

Comment: sir i have new question. what if we already had numbers in row at the table and want to get pin value from a table (not make random number ).
i tried to set a value instead of   `const pin = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);`
it means : `const pin = $("#...");`
but it doesnt works correctly , 
note : the `$("#...");` value is a dynamic value => each pin has there own value

Comment: @A_New_One : Do you mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/z8bwsumc/ ?

Comment: i think thats true . but i didnt test it yet, in my source to find out is it okey or not . thank you again for your reply sir , ill write comment here . if i couldnt create what is in my mind

Comment: @A_New_One : You are welcome. Good luck with your project!